# Why doesn't mod_proxy like recursion?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Disclaimer: I am very new to `mod_proxy` and somewhat new to `apache` in general.

I have a very simple virtual host with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myhost.mydomain


    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass /mysite http://www.google.com
    ProxyPassReverse /mysite http://www.google.com

    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `http://myhost.mydomain/mysite` it displays the expected result, ie Google's home page, but it does not send Google's images over. When I look at the source for an image, it is in terms of `myhost.mydomain` rather than a Google URI, which is expected. What isn't expected is why the images are not being fetched by `mod_proxy` and sent down to me. How do I make `mod_proxy` "recursive" a la `mod_rewrite`. In that same vein, if I am already familiar with `mod_rewrite`, why bother with `mod_proxy` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's resources on the page are in the form `img src="/images/srpr/logo3w.png"` or similar; this causes them to be fetched from the root of the site.

Take a look at how you've configured proxying; `/mysite/images/srpr/logo3w.png` is the request the client browser would have needed to send to get the image.  Switch to..

```
ProxyPass / http://www.google.com/
```

and everything ought to work.

`mod_proxy_html` is designed to alter link paths to function correctly in the context of the proxy, but don't count on it working correct for a site that you don't control, especially if any of the link building is done in client side javascript.

`mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy` serve completely different purposes; if you use the `[P]` flag in `mod_rewrite` then you're actually utilizing `mod_proxy`, but in a less efficient way than just configuring `ProxyPass`.

Comment: Thank you for the info re: mod_proxy_html, since the situation of link building through clientside js is exactly the situation im facing